# Methods for generating complex network

Tags: python-3.x, graph, networkx, networkit

I have a small graph network and I've been looking for methods that can make
use of the structural properties of the small network to generate a complex
network.
I'd like to use a method that preserves properties such as degree
distribution, clustering, etc..

Fortunately, I came across this [article]
(https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s41109-017-0054-z) that
discusses the generation of a replica of the original network followed by
network scaling.

For example,
I have generated an edge-weighted Networkx graph like the following: ( a
random graph is created for illustration),

```
import random
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
G = nx.gnm_random_graph(20, 30, seed=1)

for (u, v) in G.edges():
    G.edges[u, v]['weight'] = random.randint(0, 10)

nx.draw(G, with_labels=True)
plt.show()
print(G.edges(data=True))
```

This graph has 20 nodes. I'd like to know how to scale such Networks by a
scale factor x varying from 5 to 10. Examples will be really helpful.

Also, in the documentation
(https://github.com/networkit/networkit/blob/Dev/notebooks/User-Guide.ipynb)
it is mentioned that the supported graph data format is METIS adjacency format.
I would like to know if the networkx graph has to be converted to metis graph.
Is there an option of directly using the Networkx graph in Networkit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [nxadapter](https://networkit.github.io/dev-docs/python_api/nxadapter.html) module in NetworKit to convert graphs from networkx to NetworKit and vice versa.
In your code this would work as follows:

```
import networkit as nk
import random
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
G = nx.gnm_random_graph(20, 30, seed=1)

for (u, v) in G.edges():
    G.edges[u, v]['weight'] = random.randint(0, 10)

nx.draw(G, with_labels=True)
plt.show()
print(G.edges(data=True))

# Networkx graph to NetworKit graph
G_nk = nk.nxadapter.nx2nk(G, weightAttr='weight')
```

To generate complex networks you can also consider to use a graph generator, [here](https://networkit.github.io/dev-docs/python_api/generators.html) you can find some examples.

Comment: Thank you very much. I had a look at the graph generators. From what I understand, the generators listed in the above-mentioned link can be used for creating random graphs. I am not sure if these generators can be used for scaling an existing graph. Could you please elaborate on this?

Comment: That's true, you can use the generators to generate complex networks but not to scale existing graphs. My point is that if want to generate a complex network there are plenty of generators you can use, otherwise I am not familiar with network scaling.

Comment: Thank you. I've opened a new thread [here](https://github.com/networkit/networkit/issues/600)

Comment: @angriamn As suggested in the thread shared above I tried networkit.generators.LFRGenerator.fit(G_nk, scale=2) . But, this returns an object and I am not sure how to access the scaled graph.  Could you please help?